# CSS, PHP - Text / fonts are distorted and blurred untill the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php

I’m new to CSS and I’m having a weird issue with text / fonts on my first website. I’ve deployed my project on a LAN using IIS. On the majority of computers (Windows 7 or 10, Chrome or Opera, etc.) pages look the way they are supposed to. However, on two computers (one with Windows 7 and Chrome, another one with Windows 10 and Chrome) text appears to be blurred and distorted for a few seconds (as if loading) and then it looks normal. If you refresh the page, it loads quicker and the text appears just fine. The issue occurs on every page on these computers. I use Google fonts and thought it was the problem, then I changed it to Arial and it didn’t help at all. I also noticed that the blurred text usually comes from the result of an SQL query, so I changed it just to plain text in those divs but it didn't help.

This is what it looks like upon opening a page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dsO4.png

This is what it looks like a few seconds later or if you refresh the page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ6dp.png

For backend I use PHP and the laptop on which my website is deployed is pretty slow, could it affect the performance?

I posted the landing page with its CSS and JavaScript files on Github along with an SQL file which contains two tables (MySQL Database) storing the data shown in the screenshots.

https://github.com/allen4l/bank-website

Here is the PHP snippet which renders what is depicted in the screenshots above:

```
<div class="rates"> /*the divison has two blocks which show the exchange rates of our bank the rates of the Central Bank*/

        <div class="rates-tab-container"> /*it creates two tabs: one for the rates of our bank, another one is for the rates of the CB*/
            <button
              class="btn btntkpb"
              data-tab="1"
            >
              Exchange Rates of <span> «Dummy»</span>
            </button>

            <button
              class="btn btncb"
              data-tab="2"
            >
            Exchange Rates of <span> «the central Bank»</span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="allrates"> /*one container*/
            <div class="rate main-style tkpbrates"> /*our rates*/
                <div class="ratedate">
                    <?php echo $date_of_update?> /*fetch the date from the DB*/
                </div>
                <div class="dollar">
                    <span>$ </span>
                    Dollar: 
                </div>
                <div class="dollarSell currency">
                      <?php if ($dl_sell_dif > 0) /*I use an SQL query to determine whether yesterday's rate was greater or lower than the current one and then post the value and the corresponding icon, and it goes like this for other currencies as well*/
                      {echo $up_html;} else {
                          echo $down_html;
                        } echo ' '.$rows[0]['sell_cur'];
                      ?>
                </div>
                <div class="dollarBuy currency">
                <?php /*the same as above*/
                      ?>
                </div>

                <div class="euro">
                    <span>€ </span>
                    Euro: 
                </div>
                <div class="euroSell currency">
                <?php /*the same as above*/
                      ?>
                </div>
                <div class="euroBuy currency">
                <?php /*the same as above*/
                      ?>
                </div>

                <div class="yuan">
                    <span>¥ </span>
                    Yuan: 
                </div>
                <div class="yuanSell currency">
                <?php /*the same as above*/
                      ?>
                </div>
                <div class="yuanBuy currency">
                <?php /*the same as above*/
                      ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rate main-style cbrates">
            
                <div class="ratedate"> /*finally we repeat the same for CB rates*/
                <?php echo $date_of_update_cb?>
                </div>
                <div class="dollar">
                    <span>$ </span>
                    Dollar: 
                </div>
                <div class="dollarSell currency">
                <?php /*the same as above*/
                      ?>
                </div>
                <div class="dollarBuy currency">
                <?php /*the same as above*/
                      ?>
                </div>

              /* ......*/

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

And here is the css snippet which is used for the above-mentioned classes:

```
.rates {
max-width: 1024px;
max-height: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
}

.btntkpb {
cursor: default;
margin-right:9rem;
transform: translateY(50%);
z-index: 1;
}

.btncb {
cursor: default;
margin-left:9rem;
transform: translateY(50%);
z-index: 1;
}

.rates-tab-container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.allrates {
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
}

.rate {
height: 260px;
width: 48%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
font-size: 1.3rem;
padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.tkpbrates, .cbrates {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-gap:1em;
justify-items:stretch;
align-items:stretch;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
text-align: center;
}

.ratedate {
grid-column:1/4;
grid-row:1/2;
padding-top: 2rem;
}

.dollar {
grid-column:1/2;
grid-row:2/3;
}

.dollarSell {
grid-column:2/3;
grid-row:2/3;
}

.dollarBuy {
grid-column:3/4;
grid-row:2/3;
}

.euro {
grid-column:1/2;
grid-row:3/4;
}

.euroSell {
grid-column:2/3;
grid-row:3/4;
}
.euroBuy {
grid-column:3/4;
grid-row:3/4;
}

.yuan {
grid-column:1/2;
grid-row:4/5;
}

.yuanSell {
grid-column:2/3;
grid-row:4/5;
}

.yuanBuy {
grid-column:3/4;
grid-row:4/5;
}
```

**UPDATE**: the issue disappears when I use the html extension instead of php for the page (provided that I hardcode the content)

Comment: Without any code it is impossible to help you -> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could maybe be some script or file loading slowly. Check your network tools in the browser to monitor what's going on, to start with. And yeah, don't run a website off a laptop. Fine for testing but not for everyday use

Comment: @reyno, I'm so sorry, my bad. I've just updated the post with a link on Github to where I uploaded the code and what is necessary to make it work (an sql file, css and javascript files with images). If there is something else missing, please let me know. My apologies once again

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your reply. Yeah, I'll try to deploy it on another machine later. I just don't understand why it happens on specific machines but works smoothly on other PCs and laptops...